# Wrong key class: Text is not IntWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

This may seem like a stupid question, but I fail to see the problem in my types in my mapreduce code for hadoop

As stated in the question the problem is that it is expecting IntWritable but I'm passing it a Text object in the collector.collect of the reducer.

My job configuration has the following mapper output classes:

```
conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

And the following reducer output classes:

```
conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

My mapping class has the following definition:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>
```

with the required function:

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
```

And then it fails when I call:

```
output.collect(new Text(),new IntWritable());
```

I'm fairly new to map reduce but all the types seem to match, it compiles but then fails on that line saying its expecting an IntWritable as the key for the reduce class. If it matters I'm using 0.21 version of Hadoop

Here is my map class:

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable node = new IntWritable();
    private IntWritable edge = new IntWritable();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            node.set(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            edge.set(Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken()));
            if(node.get() < edge.get())
                output.collect(node, edge);
        }
    }
}
```

and my reduce class:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    IntWritable $ = new IntWritable(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    Text keyText = new Text();

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<IntWritable> valueList = new ArrayList<IntWritable>();

        //outputs original edge pair as key and $ for value
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            IntWritable value = values.next();
            valueList.add(value);
            keyText.set(key.get() + ", " + value.get());
            output.collect(keyText, $);
        }

        //outputs all the 2 length pairs 
        for(int i = 0; i < valueList.size(); i++)
            for(int j = i+1; i < valueList.size(); j++)
                output.collect(new Text(valueList.get(i).get() + ", " + valueList.get(j).get()), key);
    }
}
```

and my job configuration:

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(Triangles.class);
conf.setJobName("mapred1");

conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("mapred1"));

JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

Comment: It looks good. Could you post the mail, map and reduce classes

Comment: Just updated the question with the map and reduce classes, although I'm new to hadoop and don't know what the mail class is? I made this by modifying the WordCount example which I don't think includes that class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your problem is that you set the Reduce class as a combiner

```
conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
```

Combiners run in the map phase and they need to emit the same key/value type (IntWriteable, IntWritable in your case)
remove this line and you should be ok

Comment: hmm, I'll try that in a moment and see if it works, I only did that because that line is in the WordCount example and I have other map reduce jobs that have used that and I didn't have a problem.

Comment: It hasn't finished running yet but it definitely got past the problem I was having. Answer accepted. Just one thing though, why is it used in the WordCount example on the hadoop website?

Comment: The o/p of Mappers and Combiners is fed to Reducers. In the code the o/p of the combiner is Text/IntWritable and the input to the reducer is IntWritable/IntWritable which don't match, so the error. See this [article](http://philippeadjiman.com/blog/2010/01/14/hadoop-tutorial-series-issue-4-to-use-or-not-to-use-a-combiner/) on why combiners. To summarize they are used to make the job runner faster by making the map tasks do some more work on the data available locally and thereby transferring less data to the reducers.

Comment: @user1084563 Combiners run as part of the map (i.e. on the computer where the data is) if you can use them it means a more efficient process as you don't have to send the data over to the reducer. in the word count sample the map emits 1 for each word encountered, the combiner sums the numbers of each word on the same node and the reducer then produce the total for all the cluster. In this example the combiner and the reduce both do the same logic and share the same signature so they can be one class.